# Is holding a reference to another object as a member safe in this case?

Tags: c++, reference

I have a few classes, each depends on using an instance of another object in a dependency chain. It looks something like this:

```
class A {} ;

class B 
{ 
    A& m_a; 
public:
    B(A& a) : m_a(a) { } 
};

class C
{
    B& m_b;
public:
    C(B& b) : m_b(b) { }
};
```

To protect myself from holding dangling references because of order of destruction, I'm holding all of these in a container class, like this:

```
struct Data
{
    Data() : m_b(m_a), m_c(m_b) { }

    A m_a;
    B m_b;
    C m_c;
};
```

Assuming the order of the members in class `Data` matches the dependency order, is it safe to do so? Are there any pitfalls in holding these references which I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, it is safe. Each objects dependent referenced object is fully constructed prior to establishing the reference (and equally important, will be destroyed in the *opposite* order).

Answer (score 3):

It's OK. Class-members are initialized in order, in which they are declared, so:

`m_a` initialized -> `m_b` initialized with reference to `m_a` -> `m_c` initialized with reference to `m_b`.

Comment: Thanks. And what about other pitfalls? Such as copying these members outside? Or any other forbidden action I did not think of?

Answer (score 1):

No problem - C++ guarantees to construct the class members in the order they are declared, so you are safe.